# Set value field before submit

Tags: entities, forms, nodes

I'm trying to set a value before the form is submitted. The field is calculated by two other fields. One of them is a property of an entity reference. This is what I do:

```
function nodeoverlay_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state) {
    if($node->type == 'zoekertje')
    {
        $korting = $form['field_field_korting']['und'][0]['value']['#value'];
        $node = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_product_zoekertje');
        $node = node_load($node[0]['target_id']);
        $aankooprijs = $node->field_aankoopprijs['und'][0]['safe_value'];
        $price = floatval($aankooprijs - (($aankooprijs/100)*$korting));

        $form['field_verkoopprijs']['und'][0]['value']['#value'] = $price;
        $form['field_verkoopprijs']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $price;

        $form_state['field']['field_verkoopprijs']['und']['instance']['default_value'] = $price;
        $form_state['values']['field_verkoopprijs']['und'][0]['value'] = $price;
    }
}
```

I've tried different things to set my value of the field `field_verkoopprijs` but the result is always empty (and yes, my $price variable contains a float variable).

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [hook_node_submit()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7):

> This hook is intended for adjusting non-field-related properties

I think the proper place for this will be [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) . To change field there you need to set, for example:

```
$node->some_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'your value';
```

If you want to set reference field then:

```
$node->some_reference_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'] = 'your value';
```

You may also want to consider using [computed_field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module for this.

Comment: I've checked Computed field but I don't know if it's possible to set a property of entity reference